# IronPython 2.7.7 C# Integration Memory Leak

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, ironpython

I am integrating IronPython scripts to run under a C# engine. The C# engine builds a dictionary of 'ScriptValue' objects and passes it to the IronPython Script which then uses the objects to do calculations. The 'ScriptValue' object is in a separate class library and implements 'MarshalByRefObject' and is a simple .net object (stores double and bool values only). The script run happens frequently.

**First Attempt:**
I instantiated the IronPython engine and ran the scripts. As the runs progress I could see that memory usage was increasing at a fast rate. Eventually after a day or running the application crashed with an out of memory exception. I tried both keeping an instance of the IronPythonEngine alive and restarting a new instance on each run. I also tried shutting down the IronPython Engine but memory would increase consistently.

**Second Attempt:**
After researching this a lot, suggestions came up to try running the engine in a separate AppDomain and unloading the AppDomain once you are done running the scripts. I then implemented this and create a new AppDomain and unload it once a run has completed. This appears to help to a certain degree but the memory leak persists albeit it creeps up at a slower rate.

I did various memory profiling and it seems like IronPython or somewhere in DLR land unmanaged memory is not getting freed and this creeps up overtime. Managed memory seems to be getting cleared as the AppDomain is unloaded.

The C# engine itself is rather complex and interacts with MS SQL, IronPython, a Data Historian and an Asset Database. I won't go into the specifics of this as I have been able to recreate the issue by taking out all the additional components into a simple Windows Forms application.

The code I am running at the moment under a timer is:

```
private void RunEngine()
{

    ScriptEngine pythonEngine = null;
    AppDomain sandbox = null;
    ScriptSource source = null;
    ScriptScope scope = null;
    dynamic subClass = null;
    ObjectOperations ops = null;
    dynamic instance = null;
    dynamic result = null;

    Dictionary<string, ScriptValue> scriptInputValues = GetIronPythonScriptInputAttributeValues();
    Dictionary<string, ScriptValue> scriptOutputValues = GetIronPythonScriptOutputAttributes();

    // Setup PythonEngine options
    Dictionary<string, object> options = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    //options["Debug"] = ScriptingRuntimeHelpers.True;
    options["ExceptionDetail"] = ScriptingRuntimeHelpers.True;
    options["ShowClrExceptions"] = ScriptingRuntimeHelpers.True;

    // Create a sandbox to run the IronPython scripts in
    sandbox = AppDomain.CreateDomain("IronPythonSandbox",
                                                      AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence,
                                                    new AppDomainSetup() { ApplicationBase = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, ApplicationName = "IronPythonSandbox" },
                                                    new PermissionSet(PermissionState.Unrestricted));

    // Create the python engine
    pythonEngine = Python.CreateEngine(sandbox, options);
    source = pythonEngine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(@"\\server2\Projects\Customer\Development\Scripts\calculation.py");
    var compiled = source.Compile();
    scope = pythonEngine.CreateScope();
    //source.Execute(scope);
    compiled.Execute(scope);
    subClass = scope.GetVariableHandle("Calculate");
    ops = pythonEngine.Operations;
    instance = ops.Invoke(subClass, scriptInputValues, scriptOutputValues);
    result = instance.Unwrap();

    if (scriptInputValues?.Count > 0) { scriptInputValues.Clear(); scriptInputValues = null; }
    if (scriptOutputValues?.Count > 0) { scriptOutputValues.Clear(); scriptOutputValues = null; }

    result = null;
    instance = null;
    ops = null;
    subClass = null;
    scope = null;
    source = null;
    pythonEngine?.Runtime?.Shutdown();
    pythonEngine = null;
    if (sandbox != null) { AppDomain.Unload(sandbox); }
    sandbox = null;

}
```

I have stripped down the script into bare bones now to test the memory issue and it is like this and does not carry out any actual calculations as such.

```
import clr
import sys

# Import integration library to allow for access to the required .Net object types
sys.path.append(r"C:\Program Files\Company\RTCM Worker") # Include the path to the .Net Library
clr.AddReference('RTCM.Worker.IPy.Integration.Library.dll')
import RTCM.Worker.IPy.Integration.Library

import System
from System.Collections.Generic import Dictionary

sys.path.append(r"\\server2\Projects\Customer\Development\Scripts") # Include the path to the module
from constants import *
from sharedfunctions import *

import math


def Calculate(scriptInputValues, scriptOutputValues):

    returnValue = True

    try:

        # Parameter validations

        if returnValue: # Only proceed with the calculation if all inputs are valid

            ## Script logging related objects
            #ENABLE_SCRIPTLOGGING = scriptOutputValues[C_EnableScriptLogging].Value
            #SCRIPT_LOG = scriptOutputValues[C_ScriptLog].Value

            # Get all the required input parameter values
            AMB_TEMP = scriptInputValues[C_AmbientTemperature].Value
            GND_AIR = scriptInputValues[C_GroundAir].Value
            MAX_DESIGN_TEMP = scriptInputValues[C_MaximumDesignTemperature].Value
            g = scriptInputValues[C_RatingCalculationConstants_g].Value
            CONDUCTOR_DIA = scriptInputValues[C_ConductorDIA].Value
            WIND_SPEED = scriptInputValues[C_WindSpeed].Value # From lookup table and no conversion needed as this is in m/s
            DEFAULT_WIND_ANGLE = scriptInputValues[C_WindBearing].Value
            SIGMA = scriptInputValues[C_Rating_Calculation_Constants_SIGMA].Value
            CONDUCTOR_EMISSIVITY = scriptInputValues[C_ConductorEmissivity].Value
            SOLAR_ABSORPTION = scriptInputValues[C_SolarAbsorption].Value
            SOLAR_DIRECT = scriptInputValues[C_SolarDirect].Value
            GROUND_REFLECTIVITY = scriptInputValues[C_GroundReflectivity].Value
            SOLAR_DIFFUSE = scriptInputValues[C_SolarDiffuse].Value
            CONDUCTOR_SKIN_EFFECT = scriptInputValues[C_ConductorSkinEffect].Value
            CONDUCTOR_MAG_EFFECT = scriptInputValues[C_ConductorMAGEffect].Value
            CONDUCTOR_DC_RESISTANCE = scriptInputValues[C_ConductorDCResistance].Value
            CONDUCTOR_ALPHA = scriptInputValues[C_ConductorAlpha].Value


            # Destroy all referenced objects
            del AMB_TEMP
            del GND_AIR
            del MAX_DESIGN_TEMP
            del g
            del CONDUCTOR_DIA
            del WIND_SPEED
            del DEFAULT_WIND_ANGLE
            del SIGMA
            del CONDUCTOR_EMISSIVITY
            del SOLAR_ABSORPTION
            del SOLAR_DIRECT
            del GROUND_REFLECTIVITY
            del SOLAR_DIFFUSE
            del CONDUCTOR_SKIN_EFFECT
            del CONDUCTOR_MAG_EFFECT
            del CONDUCTOR_DC_RESISTANCE
            del CONDUCTOR_ALPHA
            del scriptInputValues
            del scriptOutputValues

            returnValue = True

    except System.Exception as ex:
        returnValue = False

    return returnValue;
```

Some screenshots of memory creeping up over time and you will notice unmanaged memory is creeping up:

[Start of run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWufr.jpg)

[some time later](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toV0h.jpg)

[some time later](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aggUd.jpg)

I am running out of options now. Are there any other suggestions on things to try?

A few other things I tried:

1. Setting LightweightScopes to true and it did not help.
2. Deleting objects referenced in the IronPython script using the del keyword and it did not help.

Let me know if you want to know any additional details around my setup.

Comment: As I was posting the code here I commented out a line from the code which is used to allow the Python scripts to be debugged in code.

options["Debug"] = ScriptingRuntimeHelpers.True;

Out of curiosity I took this out from the application and have it running for the last hour without a memory leak as before. I will monitor this over the next few days to see if this is actually the cause of it or not and report back.

Another thing I have introduced back is this and I will iterate through the code now to see which is helping
options["LightweightScopes"] = ScriptingRuntimeHelpers.True;

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue with memory leakage per execution of an IronPython 2.7.5 script within a C# engine.

You should manually disconnect from your MarshalByRef objects at the end of each script execution or else you may be holding on to objects. If within your MarshalByRef object(s), you have overriden the InitializeLifetimeService to prevent remoting exceptions, it is mandatory to manually disconnect as shown here:

`System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.Disconnect(MarshalByRefObj obj)`

Hopefully you've had success with removing Debug options from the engine, I'd like to know if that worked for you.

Comment: Hi Alex, Thank you for this. No it did not work with removing the debug options. I have been a bit side tracked with other things but will get back into looking at this. Could you elaborate more on disconnecting MarshalByRef objects. I am not doing any MarshalByRef at the moment. See the code I have posted in the original text. Do you have any code samples around what you specifically did around marshalling? The memory usage keeps going up.

Comment: Also, forcing GC collects would be overkill in my case but I will include it in the next release into the clients environment to see what it does to memory usage. The scripts are run quite frequently and I would need to optimize how frequently GC collection is done but as a test I will let it run on each run.

Comment: Hi Alex, I figured out what you mean when you said to disconnect MarshalByRefObj and implemented it but the result is the same as before. Memory leak still persists. I am delving more into .Net Remoting to see if there are other things I could try but at this stage it is not looking hopeful.

Comment: Hmm. Another potential route to investigate is whether you are compiling your script unnecessarily? I will continue to add to this as I think of things I looked at.

Comment: Thanks Alex, your response if greatly appreciated. Yep I am compiling the script and did that as part of the various things I was trying. I will remove the compiling and retest to see if it makes any difference or not.

Comment: Hi Alex, Tried that and still memory usage increases consistently overtime. I am letting it run for a few days to see if memory use caps at a certain amount of keeps going up and up.

Comment: Hi Alex, The memory increase is consistent after running for a few days. Feels like I am getting to a dead end now and have tried everything suggested out there without any luck.

Comment: Ya the issue is definitely a head scratcher. The solution I have come to is to not shutdown the ironpython engine but rather take care of some garbage collection yourself (a big "no, no" in Python, but it is working for me) to simulate a reset of the ironpython engine.